# How to convert or typecast to binaryInteger from string?

Tags: ios, swift, binary, bit

```
"11001001101000000100010101"

"00111000000011010000101011"
```

AND

```
= 00001000000000000000000001
```

Binary representation:

```
"11001001101000000100010101" = > 0b11001001101000000100010101

"00111000000011010000101011" = > 0b00111000000011010000101011
```

Two strings but value looks like binary and 
I want to Bitwise And Operator of two binary.

How to convert string to binary?

Comment: So you want to bitwise AND two binary strings? Do you want the result to be an `Int` or a `String`?

Comment: want the result is Int.

Comment: Then the `res` variable in Joakim Danielson's solution is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both UInt and String has init methods where you can give the radix (base ) of the number

```
let s1 = "11001001101000000100010101"
let s2 = "00111000000011010000101011"

if let binary1 = UInt(s1, radix: 2), let binary2 = UInt(s2, radix: 2) {
    let res = binary1 & binary2
    print(String(res, radix: 2))
}
```

output

> 1000000000000000000001